# UIActivityViewController CompletionBlock Issue. Does not get called when user "Cancels" message

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bug I've been stuck on for a bit and was wondering if someone can help.
My UIActivityViewController is called within a navigationController.
The issue is the completionblock is only called SOMETIMES.
Specifically for Messages and Mail
The only instance when it actually calls the completionBlock is when user sends a successful message/mail.
If user cancels, it does not call the completionBlock which causes it to hang: Though for Mail you can dismiss the modal, for messages you cannot.

Thank you!

```
let shareContent = ["Write your share content"]
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareContent,
                                                  applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)

//Completion handler
activityController.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed:
Bool, arrayReturnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) in
    if completed {
        print("share completed")
        return
    } else {
        print("cancel")
    }
    if let shareError = error {
        print("error while sharing: \(shareError.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem with your code is.... Oh, silly me.

Comment: I'm sorry! It was just the basic implementation of a activityController. I have pasted it in~

Comment: This might be silly, but shouldn't we attach the completion handler _before_ we present the activity controller?

Comment: Yes, have done that as well but no luck :(

Comment: The sample should be updated to fix the issues matt points out, if that doesn't resolve the issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit, I've determined that the issue is highly likely a conflicting cocoapod or another library.

To combat this issue, we resolved this by creating a Custom Activity that mimics the "look" of messaging but just calls the MFMessageViewController regularly. With the delegate attached to the custom activity itself.